# How to setup has and belongs to many (HABTM) association between two models?

Tags: models, cakephp-1.3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am new to cake and I am facing one problem related with association.

I am having three tables: `users`, `messages` and `messages_users` and I am using HABTM relation for this in message model as:

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(

'Users' => array (

'className' => 'User',

'join_table' => 'messages_users',

'foreignKey' => 'message_id',

'associationForeignKey' => 'reciever_id',

'conditions'=> array('MessagesUser.reciever_id' => '$this->Session->read("Id")')

)

);
```

My problem is when any user will login,he must be able to see the list of messages he got along with the senders name in the table.

But for me this relation is fetching only messages_users data,

My controller is like this,

```
<?php

class MessagesController extends AppController {

var $name = 'Messages';

//var $scaffold;

function home($id = null)

{

//$this->Message->id=$id;

//$messages_users = $this->Message->MessagesUser->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('MessagesUser.reciever_id'=>$this->Session->read("Id"))));

$messages_users = $this->Message->MessagesUser->find('all',array('fields'=>array('id','name')));

// $this->set(compact('tags'));

print_r($messages_users);

$this->set('messages_users',$messages_users);

$i=0;

foreach ($messages_users as $messages_user):

$new = $messages_users[$i]['MessagesUser']['sender_id'];

$i++;

print_r($new);

$messages = $this->Message->Users->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Users.id'=>$new)));

// print_r($messages);

$this->set('messages',$messages);

endforeach;

}

} ?>
```

So please anybody help me how to get the result for this.

Comment: The question might be better phrased as: "How to setup has and belongs to many (HABTM) association between two models"

Answer (score 0):

From the [CookBook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together):

> Remember that associations are defined
>   'one way'. If you define User hasMany
>   Recipe that has no effect on the
>   Recipe Model. You need to define
>   Recipe belongsTo User to be able to
>   access the User model from your Recipe
>   model

Have you setup the relationship in your users model to your messages model?

Setting it up like you have you'll be able to access users from the messages model but not messages from the user model.

Reference The CookBook Models section on [Has And Belongs To Many](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM) for more details.